# nvme SSD df -h reports incorrect disk usage

Tags: disk-usage, df, nvme

I helped myself with this shiny new Samsung 960 EVO 250GB, and it is super fast, I am very happy with it.

Now my disk is full, but df -h reports 33% used space...

I really don't know where to start. None of the windows disk are mounted.

```
➜  ~ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.6M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  221G   75G  136G  36% /
tmpfs           7.9G   18M  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Doing a `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x785fa4bc

Device         Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1          2048  15624191  15622144   7.5G 82 Linux swap /     Solaris
/dev/nvme0n1p2 *    15624192 488396799 472772608 225.4G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 45B474DE-DB6A-4989-8E4C-4248AF224317

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    923647    921600  450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2   923648   1128447    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1128448   1161215     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4  1161216 468860927 467699712  223G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AA707EDB-4CAC-4490-930F-D6EAA0734A91

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T Microsoft basic data
```

abd a `lsblk -f`

```
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                              
├─sda1      ntfs   Recovery 14A29502A294E98E                     
├─sda2      vfat            EC96-8D0F                            
├─sda3                                                           
└─sda4      ntfs            3EF2AEE5F2AEA11F                     
sdb                                                              
└─sdb1      ntfs            462CE7B92CE7A263                     
nvme0n1                                                          
├─nvme0n1p1 swap            29c87d8f-0d0c-41a3-a0f8-aae5da653c9e [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4            b00bf4bb-3e26-480d-80e4-207dad473844 /
```

As well the one without -f

```
nvme0n1     259:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   7.5G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 225.4G  0 part /
```

Comment: Add the output of `lsblk -f`

Comment: Go to the Samsung web site and download the "Samsung Wizard" and check that you have the latest firmware installed on the SSD.

Comment: @heynnema I cannot find the Samsung Wizard for linux. Any link for me?

Comment: @Ant I'm pretty sure Samsung Magician is Windows only. http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/magician.html

Comment: the Linux version is under Enterprise. http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/enterprise.html But if you have Windows probably better to use Windows. I could not get it to work with my  840 with Linux version.